# probability distribution for a function of multiple probability distributions

Tags: probability

I want to derive the probability distribution $Pr(A)$ of a random variable $A$. I have the the joint probability distribution $Pr(X,Y)= Pr(Y|X)*Pr(X)$ of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and the function $g:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ with $a = g(x,y)=\frac{x}{2y-x}$.

So I can find how to do this, if one has just a random variable $A$ depending on one random variable $X$ and monotonic $g$ in books and on wikipedia. But I couldn't find how to this for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ in general since I'm not even sure how the requirement to $g$ to be monotonic translates to 2d functions.

Also, while domains of $X$ and $Y$ are all natural numbers, $A$ needs to be positive, so there is an additional restriction $x<2y$. I thought of just ignoring that in the derivation and simply stating at the end that $A$ needs to be positive. But then I have to consider $g$ singular at $x=2y$. ... Any ideas?

Thanks,
Alice

Comment: Why does $A$ need to be positive?  Are you saying that $Pr(X,Y)$ comes out to be zero when $2y\leq x$?  (In any event, the case where $2y=x$ will definitely need some care.)

Comment: @tabstop This is a boiled down version of a physical problem I consider. $A$ is a radius and therefore $2y\leq x$ is beyond the scope of the model I use. I'd rather say $Pr(X,Y)$ is not defined for $2y\leq x$ than assume $Pr(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: If I'm reading what you want correctly (and I'm not all that confident that I am), then I would think you would want to modify $Pr(Y|X)$ accordingly when you build your distribution (so that it is only supported when $y\geq x/2$) so that the invalid cases aren't a concern.

Comment: @tabstop I guess I could do that. But then, how would I proceed to derive $Pr(A)$ from $Pr(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, you would sum over all the pairs $(x,y)$ where $a$ comes out to what you want. For instance $Pr(A=1) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty Pr(x,x)$, since $A$ is 1 precisely when $x=y$.  In general, you can solve $a=\frac{x}{2y-x}$ for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $a$, and so you can always write $Pr(A=a)$ as a single summation on $x$.

It's possible there's a closed form involved, although since $A$ must be in $\Bbb Q$ I would be surprised if there's a nice formula here (it certainly can't be continuous).